# Determining if a function is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$$T(p(x)) = p(x+1)$$
$$T: R[x] \to R[x]$$

Let's take $p(x), q(x) \in R[x]$

Now I need to check if $T(p(x)+q(x)) = T(p(x)) + T(q(x))$

From the definition I know that

$T(p(x)) + T(q(x)) = p(x+1) + q(x+1)$

But I wasn't sure how to calculate $T(p(x) + q(x))$ ?

Comment: Let $r(x)=p(x)+q(x)$. Then $T(r(x))=r(x+1)=p(x+1)+q(x+1)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust got it.. can I use the same to prove that $T(\lambda p(x)) = \lambda T(p(x))$ like this: $\lambda T(p(x)) = \lambda p(x+1)$ and let $r(x) = \lambda p(x)$ so $T(\lambda p(x)) = T(r(x)) = r(x+1) = \lambda p(x+1)$

Comment: Why could'nt you ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust just wanted to be sure, Thanks. you can supply an answer i'll accept it.